# Serializing extended String class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, extend

I have extended the `String` class in ruby to have a timestamp id associated to all its instances. This is how it looks at the moment:

```
 class String
        attr_accessor :id

        def get_timestamp
            @id ||= Time.now.nsec.to_i
            return @id
        end 
 end
```

I am serializing this string over the network but the String objects lose their ids once received on the other end of the network. I wonder how I can serialize and deserialize the Strings so that the associated ids are preserved.

Comment: That depends on what serializing method you are using.

Comment: I am using the default serializing that Ruby provides, simply writing an object to a socket's output stream: `socket.write "#{message}\r\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Monkeypatching Ruby classes like this is usually considered bad practice. You probably want to generate a separate class.

In order to make the `socket.write "#{message}\r\n"` call include more information, you need to override `to_s` on `String`. Beware, though! This will almost most certainly break things, as that method is usually called in a lot of places.

I have no idea what you're using this for in your code, so you should probably pick a better name, but you could do something like this:

```
class StringWithID
  attr_reader :id, :string

  def self.from_network(bytes)
    id, string = bytes.unpack("Qm0")
    new(id, string)
  end

  def initialize(id = nil, string)
    @id = id || Time.now.nsec.to_i
    @string = string
  end

  def to_s
    @string
  end
  alias :to_s :to_str

  def to_network
    [@id, @string].pack("Qm0")
  end
end
```

You could then call it something like this:

```
str = StringWithID.new("some string")
socket.write "#{str.to_network}\r\n"
```

And then on the other side of the network:

```
str = StringWithID.from_network(socket.gets)
```

Comment: Thanks but in fact extending the String class is required. I am doing _taint tracking_ of string objects. I receive strings at the input stream of a socket, tag them with timestamps, and let them flow through the code (a piece of code that I have no control of). Then, at the output stream of the socket I capture the string objects again and inspect if any of these strings were seen earlier. I cannot afford to use any class other than the String class because of the black box code. Monkey patching is in fact the best way of doing taint tracking in Ruby. Otherwise your approach is totally valid.

Comment: So you have no control of the other side of the socket, is that what you're saying? In that case, I'm afraid this isn't possible. The way you're sending the string it's just sending the raw bytes over, with no other object information.

Comment: I control only the send and receive of objects. It is more like this `socket.in -> s -> Black Box -> s -> socket.out`. Extending the class allows me to check if the string `s` entering the blackbox is the same as the one exiting it. Now take the above example and assume that I have 5 or 6 components of such among which I want to do the tracking of string `s`. That's what I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: Ok, so you could extend the string class with the `from_network` and `to_network` methods (they may need a little bit of tweaking). Note, however, that Ruby strings are mutable and with the code you have given it is possible to change a string without the id being updated.